# How to set Bot to auto welcome message or group rules to new join member or subscriber- Telegram

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot

How can i set a auto welcome message and group rules to new joining members to the group.
I saw many videos in Youtube with bots (which are created by others),
Is there any simply way to set a welcome messages with group rules with a facebook link with OWN BOT i mean the Bot  which we created

Answer (score 0):

The method `getUpdates` will give you an array of `Update`s. If the update is due to a new member entering the chat you will find `update.message.new_chat_members` which will have an array of `User`s.

So when you get an update `new_chat_members` then you can make your bot send any message you want with `sendMessage`

Check the API documentation [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) and [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage).

Comment: Is there any way to sen this welcome message only visible to the new member? I do not want to spam my group and bots can't initiate chats.

Comment: Right now there is no way to control visibility of messages for group users: everyone in the group see every message.
The only visibility control currently allowed is for keyboards (see https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup), but the message associated with it is visible to everyone anyway.